# LDAP database model

Tags: database-design, ldap

I have been studying about LDAP since three month ago,

recently,i have seen a wiki page "Database model", and i thought that LDAP backend database seem to be similar to dimensional model ?? Is it right ?

Or if no,which LDAP database model is used to reach "Quick read-Slow write" feature

Just want to understand LDAP clearly ^^

thank much for any help

regard

Comment: ^^! opps, i am newbie here, thank for your remind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LDAP is only an application protocol. It only defines how the communication should happen. The underlying database can be of anything. For example eDirectory uses [flaim](http://wiki.novell.com/index.php/FLAIM_Database_Engine) and [openldap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenLDAP#Backends) uses number of backend including berkelydb, plain ldif files, sql, it also invokes scripts(perl, shell) as a request to a ldap call, which means there is no predefined database and the scripts decides what data to fetch and from where.

ldap is generally designed to read more and write less, if you have some data that does not fall under this category then ldap may not be the right solution.

Comment: thank you,but please you explain how ldap do this : "ldap is generally designed to read more and write less" . Isn't  data access performance relies on Database model ? i thought data access operator (CRUD) should be best optimized and equivalent to each other (i mean no many differences)

Comment: ldap is not designed for that, infact ldap does not ensure the data is consistent all the time. The replication is loosely synchronized. It was designed for email and other information lookup as DAP(directory access protocol) You may want to read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.500 and http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch2/

Comment: LDAP is also a directory structure derived from X.500, and a naming scheme. Much more than just a protocol.